# How to fix: http://localhost:8000/articles/update/1

Tags: django, url

I have a url problem

when I click my update button it's sending me that url:

http://localhost:8000/article/update/1

However, I must go that url:

http://localhost:8000/articles/update/1

how can I solve this problem?

urls.py //blog

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from article import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', views.index, name="index"),
        path('about/', views.about, name="about"),
        path('articles/',include("article.urls")),
        path('user/',include("user.urls")),
      ]
```

urls.py //articles

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "article"

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/',views.dashboard,name="dashboard"),
    path('addarticle/',views.addarticle,name="addarticle"),
    path('article/<int:id>',views.detail,name="detail"),

    path('update/<int:id>',views.updateArticle,name="update"),
]
```

Comment: Since you haven't shown anything about an update button, there is no way anyone can help you.

Comment: You right, my fault. however, I solved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure behind the update button you are calling the right url
for example:

/articles/update/{{article.id}}

Comment: Thank u so much, I checked it, then I solved as u said